# Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, oledb, dbf

I need your help regarding in this error.

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

I want to export my table from SQL Server and insert it into a `.DBF` file.

Here is my code:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @sql = 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(
           ''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',
           ''dBASE IV;Database=C:\DBF\;'',
           ''SELECT TRANDATE, OLDGT, NEWGT, DLYSALE, TOTDISC, TOTREF, 
           TOTCAN, VAT, TENTNAME, BEGINV, ENDINV, BEGOR, ENDOR,
           TRANCNT, LOCALTX, SERVCHARGE, NOTAXSALE, RAWGROSS, DLYLOCTAX,
           OTHERS, TERMNUM FROM SALES123.dbf'')

           SELECT * from SampleDb.dbo.DailySales_DBF'
 Exec(@sql)
```

I already have my `.DBF` file named `SALES123.dbf`

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you and more power :D

Comment: Has it worked in the past? The most likely cause is that whatever user you're executing the SQL as doesn't have file permissions to create the temporary DSN necessary to talk to the DBASE file.

Comment: I think there are some known issue connecting from 64-bit SQL Server to a 32-bit Excel or Access database

Comment: Nope. This is my first time create a project like this that's why I'm having a trouble in trouble shooting this one.

Comment: Do you know to resolve this issue? or any way aside from my code?